# Is it ok to stop a slave mysql server for a few hours?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

What will happen if you stop a mysql slave server for a few hours(8 hours)? Can the master log all the changes it made for the last 8 hours and can you just start the slave server again and just wait for it to catch up with the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have space for the log files, you can stop it as long as you want. In extreme cases, if your data change volume is high enough, your slave won't be able to keep up. But if that's happening you need to be using different hardware or load balancing the database differently.

Comment: To add a bit on this, after you issue the `STOP SLAVE;`, you can issue `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` and check for the `Relay_Master_Log_File` field. This is the binlog from the master that this slave in particular is executing from (`Exec_Master_Log_Pos` being the position in that file that was executed last). If you can keep from that binlog onwards, you will be safe once you issue the `SLAVE START;`.

Comment: You can configure the maximum log file size and maximum number, if you haven't already done so, so make sure you have at least that much disk space available. The slave will stop reading from the master if it gets to the limit, and resume when the oldest log file has been deleted, which will happen when it starts processing the 3rd-oldest.

Comment: There's also a setting in mysql that will clean up binlogs older than X days, and I don't recall if that has any awareness of slaves, let alone *stopped* slaves. It should also be noted that slaves replay the logs *in a single thread*, so a an hour's worth of busy multi-core master activity might take several hours to replay on the slave.